# Help understand Apex class / bulkilfy

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, bulkification

I posted another question here:

[Help troubleshoot Flow hitting governor limit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318925/help-troubleshoot-flow-hitting-governor-limit#comment473675_318981)

looks like the apex class we are using may need bulkify, can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to extend the code to be able to bulkify it?

```
public without sharing class roundRobinAssigner {

    public static final integer customSettingNameLimitLength = 40;

    @InvocableMethod(label='Assign objects')
  public static void assign(list<RoundRobinAssignment> rras) {

        // what was the last user index?
        list<RoundRobin__c> RRSettings = [select id, GroupName__c, FieldName__c, Object__c, IndexOfLastUsed__c from RoundRobin__c];

        set<Id> recordIds = new set<Id>();

        map<string, list<GroupMember>> usersByGroup = new map<string, list<GroupMember>>();
        List<SObject> objectList = new List<SObject>();

        // get the records
        for (RoundRobinAssignment rra:rras){
            // default field
            if (rra.fieldName == null){
                rra.fieldName = 'OwnerId';
            }

            list<groupMember> groupUsers = new list<groupMember>();
            // see if we have it already in our map
            if (usersByGroup.get(rra.groupName) == null){
                groupUsers = [select Group.Name, GroupId, UserOrGroupId from GroupMember where Group.Name =: rra.groupName];
                //store in the map so we don't have to query about this group again
                usersByGroup.put(rra.groupName, groupUsers);
            } else {
                groupUsers = usersByGroup.get(rra.groupName);
            }
            // what kind of object is this, anyway?
            Id rId = id.valueOf(rra.recordId);
      string Obj = rid.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

            RoundRobin__c matchingRR = recordMatcher(RRSettings, rra.fieldName, Obj, rra.groupName);


            sObject so = rid.getSObjectType().newSObject(rid);
            integer nextIndex = getNextIndex(matchingRR, groupUsers);
            so.put(rra.fieldName, groupUsers[nextIndex].UserOrGroupId);

            matchingRR.IndexOfLastUsed__c = nextIndex;

            // if the original list didn't contain the matching one, we need to add it here
            boolean isNew = true;
            for (RoundRobin__c rr: RRSettings){
                // we already had that on our list
                if (rr.Id == matchingRR.Id){
                    rr.IndexOfLastUsed__c = matchingRR.IndexOfLastUsed__c;
                    isNew = false;
                }
            }
            if (isNew){
                //we hadn't seen it before
                system.debug('inserting a RR custom setting');
                RRSettings.add(matchingRR);
            }

            objectList.add(so);
    }

        update objectList;

        // because we may have incremented them
        update RRSettings;

  }

    public static integer getNextIndex(RoundRobin__c match, list<GroupMember> groupUsers){
        if (match.IndexOfLastUsed__c == null){
            // it's null, so grab the first one!
            return 0;
        } else if (match.IndexOfLastUsed__c >= groupUsers.size()-1){
            // you've used them all
            system.debug(match.IndexOfLastUsed__c + ' is the last match, which is >= the group size of ' + groupUsers.size() + 'so we are going back to 0' );
            return 0;
        } else {
            // return the next one
            return integer.valueOf(match.IndexOfLastUsed__c + 1);
        }
    }

    public static RoundRobin__c recordMatcher(list<RoundRobin__c> records, string FieldName, string Obj, string GroupName){

        for (RoundRobin__c rr:records){
            if (rr.FieldName__c == FieldName && rr.Object__c == Obj && rr.GroupName__c == GroupName){
                return rr;
            }
        }

        // we never found it, so create one
        RoundRobin__c rrNew = new RoundRobin__c();
        rrNew.FieldName__c = FieldName;
        rrNew.Object__c = Obj;
        rrNew.GroupName__c = GroupName;
        // because name is required
        rrNew.Name = nameShortener(Obj, FieldName, GroupName);

        // how "too long" is it? 
        insert rrNew;
        return rrNew;
    }

    public static string nameShortener(string Obj, string FieldName, string GroupName) {

        integer tooLongness = Obj.length() + FieldName.length() + GroupName.length() + 2 - customSettingNameLimitLength; // for separators
        if (tooLongness <=0) {
            return Obj + '-' + FieldName + '-' + GroupName;
        }

        integer wholesToChop = Math.round(Math.floor(tooLongness / 3));
        integer remainderToChop = Math.mod(tooLongness, 3);

        Obj = Obj.left(Obj.length() - wholesToChop);
        FieldName = FieldName.left(FieldName.length() - wholesToChop);
        GroupName = GroupName.left(GroupName.length() - wholesToChop);

        if (remainderToChop > 0) {
            GroupName = GroupName.left(GroupName.length() - 1);
        }

        if (remainderToChop > 1) {
            FieldName = FieldName.left(FieldName.length() - 1);
        }

        return Obj + '-' + FieldName + '-' + GroupName;
    }

    //what Process Builder/Flow Builder can reference for the input variables
  public class RoundRobinAssignment {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true label='group name')
    public string groupName;

        @InvocableVariable(required=true label='recordId')
    public string recordId;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false label='field name (default = ownerId)')
    public string fieldName;
  }


}
```

Comment: you are correct, you are doing soql inside a for loop. There are endless resources on this topic, notably [this Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk)

Answer (score 0):

You have a query in a loop. You are being as efficient as possible by caching the results, but the query itself can be removed entirely from the loop, reducing it to just a single use.

Here's the original code (note where the loop starts):

```
// get the records
for(RoundRobinAssignment rra:rras) {
// ... omitted for brevity ... //
        list<groupMember> groupUsers = new list<groupMember>();
        // see if we have it already in our map
        if (usersByGroup.get(rra.groupName) == null){
            groupUsers = [select Group.Name, GroupId, UserOrGroupId from GroupMember where Group.Name =: rra.groupName];
            //store in the map so we don't have to query about this group again
            usersByGroup.put(rra.groupName, groupUsers);
        } else {
            groupUsers = usersByGroup.get(rra.groupName);
        }
```

And add the following code before the for loop (left in to give you a reference point):

```
for(RoundRobinAssignment rra:rras) {
    usersByGroup.put(rra.groupName, new GroupMember[0]);
}
for(GroupMember mem: [select Group.Name, GroupId, UserOrGroupId from GroupMember where Group.Name =: rra.groupName]) {
    usersByGroup.get(mem.Group.Name).add(mem);
} 

// get the records
for (RoundRobinAssignment rra:rras){
```

---

However, even with this, you're going to run up against the governor limits, as you have to call this code for each user (assuming the original flow from your previous question), and ultimately, you're not caching across invocations.

To fix this, you'll need to create collections of values and pass them all in at once. It should be sufficient to simply pass in the list of lead records directly, and then process those leads inside the Apex code.

---

Given the complexity of what you appear to be trying to do, I'd say you probably should either drop the flow part, and just do it all in Apex (see [Schedulable Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)), or do the logic entirely in the flow. It's possible to do this in the Flow, but you'll suffer performance issues because of the limitations of how Flows work.

Comment: Thank you again sfdcfox...if I wrote the query that is happening in the flow into scheduled apex.... would I still run into the governor limit?

Comment: @Sgrove As long as it's bulkfied, as in my example, you should be just fine. If you're still worried about it, have the Schedulable class kick off a Batchable to complete the processing, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: I sent you an email, as i ran into an error. Hope thats ok!

Comment: I tried to add in as suggested 2 for loops before the 'main' for loop and got an error: Variable does not exist: groupName at line 20 column 114.